How to bring up an SR-IOV interface in a reliable way?
I would like to configure a single SR-IOV VF on a network interface. I have it working using the config listed below, however if I attempt to bring up the VF too soon after the PF, I get an error due to the VF not yet being ready. I could create a shell script to loop and wait for the VF to be ready, however this feels like a bit of a hack. Is there a way to handle this device interdependency in a more canonical way?
Here is the NetworkManager configuration I am using:
SR-IOV PV: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/sriovPF.nmconnection
[connection]
id=sriovPF
uuid=da82bf14-4af6-4cf6-a091-00d5ea1e73bc
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp216s0f1

[ethernet]

[sriov]
total-vfs=64
vf.0=spoof-check=true vlans=100

[ipv4]
method=disabled

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=disabled

[proxy]

SR-IOV VF: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/sriovPFv0.nmconnection
[connection]
id=sriovPFv0
uuid=0f0876aa-0aae-44e3-8360-acfc3ba194ce
type=ethernet
autoconnect=false
interface-name=enp216s0f1v0

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.2.10/30
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=disabled

[proxy]

If I attempt to bring up the VF too soon after the PF, I get the following error:
$ nmcli con up sriovPF
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/14)
$ sudo nmcli con up sriovPFv0
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device br0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).

(wait 1 min)

$ nmcli con up sriovPFv0
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/16)

This is a curious error as br0 has nothing to do with the SR-IOV Interface! If I wait one minute and try again, the VF interface comes up without error.
Any solution given does not need to use NetworkManager. I'd be happy to consider using something else to configure the network (e.g. systemd-networkd).

I solved my issue like this:

set the VF interface not to come up automatically at boot (connection.autoconnect set to false)
create a systemd service that brings up the VF interface at boot but only after NetworkManager-wait-online

[Unit]
Description=Bring up sriovPFv0 after sriovPF is up
After=network-online.target NetworkManager-wait-online.service
Requires=network-online.target NetworkManager-wait-online.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nmcli con up sriovPFv0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Unfortunately I can't recall where I got this idea from, otherwise I'd credit the source!
